# Does WM_GESTURE message work for Precision Touchpads?

Tags: winapi, touch, multi-touch

On MSDN, [Windows Touch Gestures Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543.aspx) describes various Multi-Touch Gestures that can be handled by the Win32 API.  But nowhere in the documentation does it say what type of touch it should be, whether the Gestures are only applicable to Touch Screens, or if they can also be received by [Precision Touchpads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/windows-precision-touchpad-industrial-design-guide).  Does anyone know?

Comment: Precision TouchPad lacks API right now, vote here to let Microsoft know we need it: https://aka.ms/Uun1l5